# Do you know the address of some server with ftp access?

Tags: ftp, ip-address

I need to test something using ftp.

Is there some public server allowing ftp access to its files? What is a good way to search for such servers?

Comment: Both ftp.microsoft.com and ftp.apple.com have an odd assortment of files, perhaps linked to from other places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need anonymous read ftp access, you could of course find some Linux mirrors

http://google.com/search?q=ftp+linux+mirror

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking for an open public server, you may want to take a USB drive (or use your hard drive) to run an install-free, easily set up FTP server. Portable apps like [Quick'n Easy FTP Server](http://www.pendriveapps.com/quickn-easy-ftp-server-lite/) would work (Windows only). It isn't hard to install your own FTP server on your local machine for testing.

Answer (score 0):

on some free hosting services you can upload files via FTP (but some of them restrict file types to upload).

you can also use solution from @thepurplepixel (another answer). if you have to access from a computer of other network but the host FTP server has not a real IP, you can download a software from www.no-ip.com to allow you to access it.